# ASP.NET integration test - TestHost always return 500 Internal server error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, xunit.net, asp.net-core-testhost

I am currently using xUnit to write integration tests and so fast I only attempted to write a single test for my AuthController to check if the authentication works (It works btw. I just want to have tests).

I do not know what I am setting up wrong but every time I run my test I get a 500 Internal Server error:

```
Failed   AuthControllerIntegrationTests.CanLogin
Error Message:
 System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.19]     AuthControllerIntegrationTests.CanLogin [FAIL]
Failed   AuthControllerIntegrationTests.CanLogin
Error Message:
 System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
```

My test looks like this:

```
[Fact]
public async Task CanLogin()
{
    var webHostBuilder =
      new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build())
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

    using (var server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder))
    using (var client = server.CreateClient())
    {
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

      object password = new {
          password = "password"
      };
      var httpResponse = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/authenticate", password);

      httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

I dont even know how to debug this...all I see in visual studio code debugger is the 500 response. Halp

**EDIT**:
Here is the controller action that I would like to test:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("authenticate")]
public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]AuthDTO input)
{
      var token = _authService.Authenticate(input.Password);

      if (token == null)
      return BadRequest(new { message = "Incorrect password!" });

      return Ok(new
         {
             token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token)
         });
}
```

I've tried modifying the controller to always return an Ok Http response, but in the test I still got a 500 internal server error.

Comment: Can you share the code of your Action which belongs to the Post method in the Authenticate controller?

Comment: I've added the controller action to be tested.

Comment: Oh wait thank you!! I'm so dumb...I was posting to the wrong route.

Comment: I have no idea why it returns a 500 error though

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simply that I am a dum-dum, and I was trying to post the request to `/api/authenticate` instead of `/api/auth/authenticate`